# Как при нажатии Jbutton сделать кнопку неактивной на определенное время?

Tags: java, swing, button

Есть кнопка, предположим JButton button которая по умолчанию активна. необходимо чтобы когда пользователь нажимал эту кнопку, повторное нажатие кнопки становилось доступным только через секунду. При этом поток не должен останавливаться!
Понимаю что это должно быть очень легко, но почему то ничего не идет в голову.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Помог new Timer()

вот примерный отрывок кода, который прописан в ActionListener данной кнопки:

```
// после нажатия на кнопку, делаем её недоступной
button.setEnabled(false);
    new Timer().schedule(
        new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            // Делаем кнопку доступной после 1 секунды
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
     }, 1000);
```